# Laravel cron entry not running repeatedly

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, cron

I have created a command in laravel to update my entity status every minute. In my Kernel.php, I have this:

```
/**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')
        //          ->hourly();
        $schedule->command('solicitation:update')
                  ->everyMinute();
    }
```

When I run `solicitation:update` or `php artisan schedule:run`, the command is executed perfectly. Then, I run the command `* * * * * php /home/nigellima/Dropbox/Laravel/plataformaTS/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` to have the task be run every minute, but nothing happens. I have checked my cli package, moved the project to `/var/www/` on a remote server but the command is never executed.
What am I missing?

I'm using Laravel 5.6 on Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you running that command in the command line? You should put that in the crontab file.. run `crontab -e` and put that command there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the full path to executables in cron. To find the location of PHP, execute `which php` by the command line. Then update your cron entry accordingly, for example if the path is `/usr/bin/php`:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/nigellima/Dropbox/Laravel/plataformaTS/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

If it still doesn't work, you will have to check your log files to get the actual error. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log.

Comment: Hi @Mike, thanks for answering. I forgot to mention, but I also tried that. The `which php` returned me the same path. But nothing seems to happen.
I'm checking if it is working by info messages in laravel.log. Would cron return the tasks to somewhere else?

Comment: Get rid of the `/dev/null 2>&1` part since that will suppress all output, including errors.

Comment: I got rid of the `>> /dev/null 2>&1` and got the message "`No command 'app' found, but there are 16 similar ones
app: command not found`"

Comment: Doing a search for that error shows a few results, but none seem to have any actual solution, so unfortunately I don't think I will be able to help you much more.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that all the results I can find are from the last 4 days. Looks like this could be a bug with Laravel. You might want to consider filing a bug report https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mike for your help. I will file this as a bug.